# Dockerfile golang build

Tags: docker, go

I am building my Go application. I am getting error like below

```
# cd .; git clone https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter /go/src/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter Cloning into
'/go/src/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter'... fatal: unable to
access 'https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter/': Could not
resolve host: github.com package github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter:
exit status 128
The command '/bin/sh -c go get ./' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

docker file.

```
# install dependencies first
RUN go get ./

RUN go build

CMD if [ ${APP_ENV} = production ]; \
    then \
    main; \
    else \
    go get github.com/pilu/fresh && \
    fresh; \
    fi

EXPOSE 8080
```

build command:

```
docker image build -t test:1.0 .
```

Thanks. Any help please?

Comment: `Could not resolve host: github.com package github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter: exit status 128 ` This clearly says your docker can't find the route to the github domain (DNS). So this means your container probably doesn't have internet connection. Can you look at your iptables and check that the docker group is in here ?

Comment: I found this is something with https rsa keys. I plan to remove the build  inside docker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Check DNS server
2. Check internet connection
3. You can clone the repository with a script in a folder, and then copy the folder to the docker and build the project. Example

   ```
   FROM golang:1.9 as builder  
   RUN mkdir -p /go/src/folder   
   WORKDIR /go/src/folder    
   COPY src/ .  
   RUN go get -d  
   RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .    



   FROM alpine:latest  
   WORKDIR /
   COPY --from=builder /go/src/folder/app .  
   CMD ["/app"]
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I have some libraries outside the directory of dockerfile. How can I copy those to build it. ? I think we cannot copy parent directory. Any ways to do ?